# "net use" in PowerShell without specifying drive

Tags: powershell

With "net use", you could do the following:

```
net use \\server /user:domian\username
```

It would then prompt for a password, and any further CIFS connections made to that server using any program (cmd, Explorer, Word, etc) would automatically use that credential.

Is there an equivalent way of doing this in PowerShell? I know New-PsDrive usually provides the answer for "net use", but it requires a drive letter to map:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-PsDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server -Credential domain\user
cmdlet New-PSDrive at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: 
New-PSDrive : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is an empty string.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-PsDrive -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server -Credential domain ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-PSDrive], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

I don't want to map a drive, I just want to say "when I connect to this server, use this credential".  Is there a way?

Comment: Honestly, if you can, stick with `net-use` over `New-PSDrive`. Way easier to deal with in my experience

Comment: Well, my use-case is in a startup script, so I don't have to open a command prompt each day to enter my admin account credentials for two servers that use almost daily.  I have a startup script already that shows me a GUI that lets me select whether I want to startup Outlook, Skype, and my softphone; I want to add this to it.  And, I don't want to store my password in that script; I want it to prompt.  I guess I can live with it prompting in a console window if that's the best answer that's out there, but I'd be disappointed in PowerShell; I thought it could do most anything these days.  ;-)

Comment: You can have at min 2 SMB-mappings per server if you use the servername for the first one and the IP for the second one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `cmdlet New-SMBMapping` is (by and large) functionally equivalent to `New-PSDrive`. However, the equivalent parameter `-LocalPath` (`-Name` in `New-PSDrive`) is not required so you shouldn't get the above error.

Comment: Excellent, this looks to be exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this `New-SMBMapping` cmdlet! We were hitting this `Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again` error. We discovered that `New-PSDrive` does actually create an SMB mapping; `Get-SMBMapping` tells you. Apparently Windows clients have a limitation of only allowing one set of credentials per SMB mapping. With `Remove-SMBMapping` this mapping can be removed. And another pair of credentials can be added. Great!

Comment: Glad it helped, @Carlin'tVeld!

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't want to store plain-text passwords in their scripts, but rather ask the user for the credentials:

```
$credential = Get-Credential
New-SmbMapping -RemotePath \\server -UserName $credential.UserName -Password $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
```

Source: https://itluke.online/2019/06/04/how-to-manage-powershell-cmdlets-requiring-plain-text-passwords/

Answer (score -2):

net use * \server\share /options

Comment: Please add some explanation and link to official documentation to your answer such that others can learn from it (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)